# Cases: Can I show more text per email in the Emails related list?

Tags: email

When I view a Case record, the Emails related list looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bis5Z.png

Is it possible to have more of the email message shown instead of just one line?  I'm fine with the height of the entire row increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot customize the Email related list on Cases.  Try removing then adding a Email related list to a Case page layout and you'll see what I mean.

Basically your only other option would be to implement a VF page either as a inline related list or as a detail page for the Case record.  One other thing you could try (very much unsupported) is injecting javascript via a home page component to modify the DOM of the email related list to change the column widths.